# Call Api from WebClient() post To HttpClient() post with authentication Headers

Tags: c#

I have this code written in deprecated WebClient and I have to update using HttpClient.
The WebClient implementation works correctly but HttpClient no, where am I doing wrong?

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{   
    wb.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    wb.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    wb.Headers.Add("user_key", "USER_KEY");
    wb.Headers.Add("Session_key", "SESSION_KEY");

    String payload = "{" +
      "    \"address\": \"via xxx\", " +
      "    \"cell\": \"+393393939393\", "
      "}";
    var response = wb.UploadString("https://..../API/subaccount", "POST", payload);
    // OK       
}

using (HttpClient cli = new())
{
    String payload = "{" +
      "    \"address\": \"via xxx\", " +
      "    \"cell\": \"+393393939393\", "
      "}";

    cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic ");
    cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user_key", "USER_KEY");
    cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access_token", "SESSION_KEY");

    var response = cli.PostAsJsonAsync("https://..../API/subaccount", payload).Result;

    //StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

}
```

Comment: The requests don't have the same headers. That's probably the source of your issues. Does the server return a response body with that 400 status code?

Comment: To clarify, you're manually adding the following headers to the `WebClient` request: Content-Type, user_key, and Session_key. To the `HttpClient` one you're manually adding hese headers: Accept, Authorization, user_key, Access_token. The `PostAsJsonAsync` method will also be adding Content-Type. I recommend making your requests through Telerik's Fiddler or against https://webhook.site/ to see how they differ.